# Delay in audio for Mic to speaker direct streaming application Android

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, java-native-interface, microphone

I am trying to built a mic application, sound from mic is directly played by speaker.The problem is there is a delay in sound heard. Code is given below. Is there a way to avoid this delay? I have heard that we can avoid this by adding native code in c/c++ and then call it from java. Is it possible? If so how?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    boolean isRecording; 
    AudioManager am;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        Record record = new Record();
        record.run();

    }
    public class Record extends Thread
    {

        static final int bufferSize = 200000;
        final short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];
        short[] readBuffer = new short[bufferSize];

        public void run() {
            isRecording = true;
            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
            int buffersize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(11025,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
            AudioRecord arec = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 11025, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,buffersize);
            AudioTrack atrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 11025, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
            am.setRouting(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL, AudioManager.ROUTE_EARPIECE, AudioManager.ROUTE_ALL);
            atrack.setPlaybackRate(11025);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
            arec.startRecording();
            atrack.play();
            while(isRecording) {
                arec.read(buffer, 0,
                        buffersize);
                atrack.write(buffer, 0,
                        buffer.length);
            }
            arec.stop();
            atrack.stop();
            isRecording = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `buffersize` coming out to be?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Use this class to set up native audio on Android: https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine/tree/master/Superpowered/AndroidIO

You can find example projects there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can try this library called [superpowered](http://superpowered.com/) that claims to have low latency audio instead of writing your own native code. 
Hope this works for you. the source is also available on git hub.